# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable - Form SelectField issue

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

The problem relates to the use of the `SelectField` option where I want to offer all clubs from the database to the use and accept back the chosen club when they complete the form.

The list of clubs is correctly provided on the form but when one is selected and the submit button is hit I get this message:

> "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" message.

My Routes code :

```
@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    clubs = []
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        clubnumber = int(form.club.data) +1
        usernumber = clubnumber * 1000000
        nextuser = (db.session.query(func.max(User.usernum)).filter(User.usernum<usernumber).scalar() or 0)
        print(nextuser)
        nextuser = nextuser +1
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, usernum=nextuser,club=form.club.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(_('Congratulations, you are now a registered user! %(nextuser)s!'))
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        clubrows = Club.query.all()
        for club in clubrows:
            clubs.append(club.clubnum)
            clubs.append(club.clubname)
        form.club.choices = [(row.clubnum, row.clubname) for row in Club.query.all()]
    return render_template('auth/register.html', title=_('Register'),  form=form)
```

My form code :

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(_l('Username'), validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField(_l('Email'), validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField(_l('Password'), validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        _l('Repeat Password'), validators=[DataRequired(),
                                           EqualTo('password')])
    club =SelectField(_l('Club' ))
    submit = SubmitField(_l('Register'))

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError(_('Please use a different username.'))

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError(_('Please use a different email address.'))
```

The full error text received :

> [2019-09-29 12:40:41,359] INFO in **init**: Microblog startup  *
>   Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 12:40:47] "GET /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> [2019-09-29 12:41:09,845] ERROR in app: Exception on /auth/register
>   [POST]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 2446, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1820, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
>   line 39, in reraise
>       raise value
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1935, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>
> File "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\app\auth\routes.py",
>   line 54, in register
>       if form.validate_on_submit():
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py",
>   line 101, in validate_on_submit
>       return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py",
>   line 310, in validate
>       return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py",
>   line 152, in validate
>       if not field.validate(self, extra):   File "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py",
>   line 195, in validate
>       self.pre_validate(form)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py",
>   line 471, in pre_validate
>       for v, _ in self.choices:
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>   127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 12:41:09] "POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something going wrong in your validatos, since `File "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\app\auth\routes.py", line 54, in register if form.validate_on_submit():` is among your errors. Are you sure your validators are working as expected? Maybe try to set a breakpoint on those.

Another thing I have had issues with in the past is selecting an element from an empty list. So instead of :

```
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError(_('Please use a different username.'))
```

you could try:

```
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data)
        if len(user) > 0:
            user = user.first()
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_('Please use a different username.'))
```

and similar for `validate_email`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Zephyrus, unfortunately the line "if len(user)..." returns "TypeError: object of type 'BaseQuery' has no len()". I'm not sure why it does this, especially given that it returns the error even if I have entered a duplicate username (when data should be returned).  This might not help anyway as I hope to have nothing returned (if it returns > 0 then it is a duplicate user/email).